# await in map in a stream

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have the following stream:

```
  Stream<List<Product>> products() {
    //Get Products from Cloud Firestore
    return productCollection.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents.map((document) {
        //Get image metadata of each product from Firebase Storage
        Future<StorageMetadata> _metadata = imageRef
            .child('${document.documentID}/${document.data['mainImage']['name']}')
            .getMetadata()
            .catchError((onError) => print('Error: $onError'));
        //After getting metadata, create product objects with data gathered above
        return Product.fromEntity(ProductEntity.fromSnapshot(
            document, ProductImageEntity.fromMetadata(_metadata)));
      }).toList();
    });
  }
```

I need the product object to be returned *after* the metadata has been retrieved from Firebase Storage. I'm new to asynchronous programming and am having trouble doing this without changing the stream return type to a Future. How can this be done?

Comment: You might want to look at [`asyncMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.0/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html).

Comment: @Irn `asyncMap` can only be applied to the snapshots stream. I need to await in the map for the list of documents to get the metadata. Could you clarify how asyncMap can be of use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it by doing the following:

```
  Stream<List<Product>> products() {
    //Get Products from Cloud Firestore
    return productCollection.snapshots().asyncMap((snapshot) {
      return Future.wait(snapshot.documents.map((document) async {
        //Get image metadata of each product from Firebase Storage
        StorageMetadata _metadata = await imageRef
            .child(
                '${document.documentID}/${document.data['mainImage']['name']}')
            .getMetadata()
            .catchError((onError) => print('Error: $onError'));
        //After getting metadata, create product objects with data gathered above
        return Product.fromEntity(ProductEntity.fromSnapshot(
            document,
            ProductImageEntity.fromMetadata(_metadata),
        ));
      }).toList());
    });
  }
```